# Need to make a box using * and methods

Tags: java

```
package methods;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisplayBox {

    public static void box (int dimensions){ 

         for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < dimensions; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" *");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }        

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);  

        int length, width ; 

        System.out.println ("Please enter the length of the box"); 
        length = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println (" Please enter the width of the box");
        width = input.nextInt(); 

        input.close(); 


        box (length); 
        box (width);


    }

}
```

I need to make a program that will make a box using asterisk and i need to use methods to do so. i was able to make the method that makes the actual box but the problem is the dimensions. It doesn't consider them as a whole, it creates a box for the length and box for width. Like for example if i input length = 5 and width = 2 it will create a box 5*5 and another 2*2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify **both** dimensions to the box-creating function:

```
public static void box (int length, int width){ 

     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }        

}
```

Now call the function **once**, with both parameters:

```
box (length, width);

// box (length); // removed
// box (width); // removed
```